# How to deploy to Wildfly Cluster using Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, bamboo, wildfly-cluster

I am creating CI and CD build process in Bamboo. Our applications are deployed in a Wildfly 9.0.2.Final server (which is clustered). Example, our deployment environment is as follows:

- DEPLOYMENT (MASTER server)
- DEV
- QA
- PRE_PROD

How do I configure my stage to include deployment to Wildfly cluster as Bamboo doesn't have Wildfly plugin to include?

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo pipeline can be configured in multiple way. You can create a java code to invoke Wildfly rest API for deployment and include that as a script task.

Comment: I (and possibly others) would have really loved to find some example code to start from :-)